# CSS3 Transition that is in progess, how to get goal value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, transition

I have two divs over each other. One is fading out and one is fading in. How to use javascript (or jquery) to get the goal value of opacity to know which one is fading in and which is fading out?

fiddle of demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ppEc3/

what im trying to do is get the height of the div that is fading in and then set the red divs height to this height.

code for fiddle:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
    #content {
        position:relative;
        background-color:red;
    }
    .page {
        position: absolute;
        width: 200px;
        background-color: #dfdfdf;
        opacity: 0;
        transition: opacity 1s;
    }

    #radio1:checked ~ .p1 { opacity: 1; }
    #radio2:checked ~ .p2 { opacity: 1; }
</style>

</head>
<body>
<div id="content">
<input type="radio" id="radio1" name="nav" checked="checked" />
<label for="radio1">Page 1</label>
<input type="radio" id="radio2" name="nav" />
<label for="radio2">Page 2</label>

<div class="page p1" style="height:200px;">page 1</div>
<div class="page p2" style="background-color:steelblue;height:100px;">page 2</div>

<script>
    var input = document.querySelectorAll('input');
    [].forEach.call(input,function(el) {
        el.addEventListener('change',function(){
            setTimeout(sizeToContents, 100);
        },false);
    });

    function sizeToContents() {
        var page1 = document.querySelector('.p1');
        var page2 = document.querySelector('.p2');

        var p1Opacity = window.getComputedStyle(page1, null).opacity;
        var p2Opacity = window.getComputedStyle(page2, null).opacity;
        alert("p1Opacity=" + p1Opacity +"\np2Opacity=" + p2Opacity);
        document.querySelector('#content').style.height = document.querySelector('.page[opacity=1]');
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Post some code please that you tried??

Comment: Aren't you the one fading these elements, shouldn't you know what you're doing ?

Comment: You'll have to search the CSS and JS for it

Comment: The elemetns are fading based on css selectors. Ill post demo code.

Comment: Added demo. Note demo has 2 div pages, real application has multiple divs

Answer (score 0):

If you toggled opacity by setting `.style.opacity` then you can find goal value by reading `.style.opacity` even if its during transition. i havent tested it but it should work same way if you apply opacity change through class, i think, someone else would need to confirm this.

if you use `getComputedStyle` you will get the opacity at the actual point in transition.